# Consulta sobre como agregar el nombre de una pregunta con base en un resultado y agregar el nombre al final de un DataFrame en python

Tags: python, dataframe

Muy buenas a todos. Soy nuevo programando en Python y en general tengo la siguiente duda la cual agradecería sus consejos para orientarme en lo que estoy intentando hacer.

```
Tengo el siguiente DataFrame.

nototal=ndf.iloc[:,0:19]
```

[image: DataFrame inicial]

```
UañoTotal=nototal.loc[nototal["Año"]=="2020"]
añomax=ndf.loc[ndf["Año"]=="2020",["Año","Mes"]]

Del DataFrame anterior extraje los valores máximos por cada fila usando el comando `.max(axis=1).` Los resultados los uní a otro DataFrame obteniendo lo siguiente.

añomax.loc[:,"Valor importacion"]=UañoTotal.max(axis=1)
```

[image: DataDrame al cual se le desea agregar la nueva columna con el nombre de la columa del resultado que se logra apreciar]

Mi pregunta es la siguiente. Como puedo agregar una nueva columna con los nombres de las columnas correspondientes al resultado obtenido del máximo de las filas ?

```
Ejemplo: 
Año=2020
Mes=Enero
Valor importación=904600        
Ubicación= X (País el cual en la fila 144 es el máximo)


Gracias por su colaboración. Saludos.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobre el mismo fichero que empleas para obtener el valor máximo `.max(axis=1)`, aplica el método `.idxmax(axis=1)` y te dará la columna correspondiente, en este caso el nombre del país. Entiendo que con tu ejemplo se sacaría con `UañoTotal.idxmax(axis=1)`